# Weird issue with malloc

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc

I was doing a simple code to open a file with a matrix but I got a weird error. Here's my code:

```
char** CM;
char** ACM;
int lines, columns;
int i, j;

//read file
FILE* file = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
fscanf(file, "%i %i", &lines, &columns);
CM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines);
ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines);
for(i=0; i<lines; i++)
{
    CM[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*columns+1);
    ACM[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*columns);
    fscanf(file, "%s", CM[i]);
    CM[i] = (char*)realloc(CM[i], sizeof(char)*columns);//don't need \n
    printf("%s\n", CM[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<lines; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", CM[i]);
}
```

But it happens that the output is not what I expected:

```
00000
01010
01010
01100
00000

��6
01010
01010
01100
00000
```

If I comment `ACM[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*columns);` it works with no no problem. I even used GDB to see what was going on and I got this :

```
23          ACM[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*columns);
2: CM[0][0] = 48 '0'
3: CM[1][1] = 49 '1'
4: i = 4
(gdb) 
24          fscanf(file, "%s", CM[i]);
2: CM[0][0] = -80 '\260'
3: CM[1][1] = 49 '1'
4: i = 4
```

Please, could someone tell me what's going on with my code?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If it is the latter you shouldn't be using `malloc`.

Comment: Yet another bug that would be fixed by not using `sizeof(type)` in malloc

Comment: There must be dozens of duplicates of this question. Got a link @M.M?

Comment: *I was doing a simple code* -- It would be a lot more simpler if you used `std::string` and/or `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But the jury is still out on if this is `c++` or not. No indicators in the code unfortunately.

Comment: True enough. C with a redundant cast or C++ with obsolete reference material. But C++ is tagged, so C++ options should be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(char)*lines)` allocates enough memory to hold `line` number of `char`s. You need enough memory to hold `line` number of `char*`s. Hence, you need to use `sizeof(char*)` instead of `sizeof(char)`.

```
CM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines);
ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines);
```

As a matter of good coding practice, use:

```
CM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*CM)*lines);    // CM  -> sizeof(*CM)
ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*ACM)*lines);  // ACM -> sizeof(*ACM)
```

That would prevent errors of the kind you ran into.

Comment: @RafaelMarinho, The argument to `sizeof` can be a type or an expression. When it is an expression, its type is used to come up with the size. When you use `*CM` as argument to `sizeof`, tit evaluates to expression of type `char*`, which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines);
```

You are allocating lines chars, not lines char*s

Answer (score 0):

With `char **CM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines)` and `char **ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines)`, you allocate a sequence of characters, though you should allocate a list of pointers.

Write `char **CM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines)` and `char **ACM = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines)` instead.

As a general rule, the return type (`char**` in your case) usually has one more star than the type inside the `malloc`, i.e. (`char*` in your case).

Note further, that in C you usually do not cast the result of malloc, whereas in C++ you have to cast. BTW: `malloc` is rarely used in C++.